# How to allow anyone to join my github team without them having to ask me

Tags: github-api

Currently I have an GitHub repo that I use for collaboration. I want anyone to be able to join it.
GitHub currently requires users to first find me (there is no form to request) and ask me and then they are mailed an invitation which they then have to accept.

I'm guessing there is an app out there for this but I can't find it.

I'm looking for either an integration that takes a turns a issue comment into a team add, or form the user can request an invite from.

Answer (score 0):

[Forking a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) remains the official way to contribute without asking. Then the contributor can make a pull request back to the original repo.
The goal is to "manage" (through PR review) the flow of contribution.

The other alternative would be to add several people owner of an [organization team](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-organization-members-to-a-team/): that way, you would be the only one people would have to ask in order to be collaborators.

Comment: In this case I need this to allow users to label issues and assign them self to an issue, not to submit code.

Comment: @djay I am afraid this is collaborator only, and I don't know of a way to open collaboration to everyone. Maybe GitHub support does?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an organization that you're trying to add members to, there is already some automation around that.

[JazzBand](https://jazzband.co/) allows anyone to join the organization. [Their website](https://github.com/jazzband/website) uses the same mechanisms as [add-to-org](https://github.com/benbalter/add-to-org) to add people to an organization.

Looking at their source code, it appears both use the GitHub API to [add members to an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership).

```
PUT /orgs/:org/memberships/:username
```

That said, if this is a personal repository, you'll instead want to follow the API to [add a collaborator](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator)

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators/:username
```

It's likely you could modify either of those projects to fit this need. Cheers!